# Plotting data points with x axis advancing in 0.5 steps

Tags: plotting

I'm still pretty new to Mathematica and i want to plot the following data points with the x axis advancing in 0.5 steps:

```
OG[6] = 1.0685458987703726`;
OG[5.5] = 1.0649776023558106`;
OG[5] = 1.0585;
OG[4.5] = 1.046957482313205`;
OG[4] = 1.0453;
OG[3.5] = 0.9951879076222613`;
OG[3] = 0.9597;
OG[2.5] = 0.8761019519547198`;
OG[2] = 0.8023;
OG[1.5] = 0.809720272706028`;
OG[1] = 1.0542;
OG[0.5] = 1.4881005040525765`;
OG[0] = 1.9194;
```

The datapoints correspond to a upper price limit (number in brackets) in a financial market model. I wrote the datapoints together from different simulation runs so there is no function that gives me all of these.

When i try to plot them using the following code:

```
OG[P_]:= P
ListLineplot[Table[OG[P],{P,0,6,0.5}]]
```

The function of `OG[P_]` is random because i thought i need a function for `Table` to work.

I get this result which has nothing to do with the data I wanted to plot and the x axis only shows whole numbers.

[image]

My question is how do i plot this correctly so that the x axis advances in 0.5 steps and it plots my datapoints?
Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Look up `DataRange`. Also, you don't need `Table[]` for plotting values, since you can do `ListLinePlot[{1.9194, 1.4881005040525765, (* everything else *)}]` directly.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Table[{P, OG[P]}, {P, 0, 6, 0.5}]]` will do the plot and use a horizontal increment of 0.5. If you don't include the `{P, }` or if you just use the raw list of numbers, it will use a horizontal increment of 1.0, not 0.5

Comment: @Bill ... except if you use `DataRange`.

Comment: @J.M. ok thx but is there a way to plot the values so that `OG[0]`has the coordinates `(0, 1.9194)` and ÒG[1]` the coordinates (0.5,  1.4881005040525765)? So you can see in the graph which value corresponds to which upper limit.

Comment: @anderstood There are almost always a dozen different ways of accomplishing anything in Mathematica, almost always a few of which are completely incomprehensible. Pick one that you can remember and can likely use without making too many mistakes and stick with it

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to define `OG` in this way. I would first try to get your data into a form like this (there can be many ways to do this, depending on how you want to enter your data):

```
data = {{0., 1.9194}, {0.5, 1.4881}, {1., 1.0542}, {1.5, 0.80972}, {2., 
  0.8023}, {2.5, 0.876102}, {3., 0.9597}, {3.5, 0.995188}, {4., 
  1.0453}, {4.5, 1.04696}, {5., 1.0585}, {5.5, 1.06498}, {6., 
  1.06855}};
```

`ListLinePlot` will take this and plot this in the way I think you want:

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: ListLinePlot, plain]

If you want to modify the $x$-axis to be in increments of 0.5, you can use the `Ticks` option:

```
ListLinePlot[
 data,
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 6, 0.5], Automatic}
]
```

[image: ListLinePlot, modified ticks]

(Of course, there's a lot more you can play with, formatting-wise; this is just a "basic" version you can start from.)

---

To give some insight into what (I think) is happening with your code above, is to note that the values of `P` that `Table[OG[P], {P, 0, 6, 0.5}]` goes through are non-integers (see [Types of Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypesOfNumbers.html)), whereas when you enter your data as, for example, `OG[0] = 1.9194;`, the `0` "argument" of `OG` is an integer.

So, when `Table[OG[P], {P, 0, 6, 0.5}]` looks for `OG[0.]` (for example), it doesn't find `OG[0.]` from the list of "`OG[ ] =`" lines, so it instead goes the `OG[P_] := P` line to figure out `OG[0.]` (`0`, according to `OP[P_]:=P`). You can see how this happens for all the "integer" values of `P` in your table:

[image: Table of OGs]

Another thing to note is that `ListLinePlot[{y1,y2,…}]` plots points `{1,y1},{2,y2},...`, so even if you were to plot `ListLinePlot[{1.9194, 1.4881005040525765, ...}]`, the $x$-values would still be "incorrect".

Even in this case, you can, of course, still mess with the ticks to get the appearance you want, but I think a solution similar to the one I wrote above will be more straightforward.

Hopefully all this makes sense and is (at least a little bit) helpful!